# Could we have a syntax summary displayed in all chat rooms?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

As illustrated by this chat excerpt, some kind of syntax summary would be appreciated to quickly know what the possibilities are when it come to write some messages.

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img641/355/chatsyntax.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img641/355/chatsyntax.png)

Even if an array wouldn't fit in the page, at the very least a link to a different page detailing the various syntax options would be welcomed.

Can you think of other solutions to integrate that "syntax options" list within the chat room page itself?

Comment: For now, the FAQ link is enough (I hadn't clicked on it right from the start of my session), but the FAQ section for the syntax could be expended and detailed (illustrated) in its own page.

Comment: Did you spend all that time on making the cool torn page effect? How do I do that without having photoshop?

Comment: @George: the torn page effect is mandatory in order to be meme-compliant: see comments of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775. I have being following that standard for well over a year now. As for how I make those screenshots, see comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306880/how-can-i-install-eclipse-on-windows-7-64-bit or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685467/eclipse-keyboard-shortcut-goto-function-name/2685618#2685618

Comment: @Marc: thank you! Although I suppose I cannot see exactly what you did just yet.

Comment: It seems the image in your post is broken. Can you please fix it?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog Ten years later, I am not surprised this picture is no longer available. I don't seem to find a suitable replacement, though.